# Parsing with SAX and handling character entities

Tags: parsing, sax, mathml, character-entities

I am parsing a MathML expression with SAX (although the fact that it's MathML may not be completely relevant).  An example input string is

```
<math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
     <mrow>
          <mo>&lambda;</mo>
     </mrow>
</math>
```

In order for the SAX parser to accept this string, I expand it a bit:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <!DOCTYPE doc_type [
          <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
          <!ENTITY amp "&#38;">
]>
<body>
     <math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
          <mrow>
               <mo>&lambda;</mo>
          <mrow>
     </math>
</body>
```

Now, when I run the SAX parser on this, I get an exception:

```
[Fatal Error] :5:86: The entity "lambda" was referenced, but not declared.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity "lambda" was referenced, but not 
                               declared.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
```

However, I know how to fix that.  I simply add this line to the string being parsed:

```
        <!ENTITY lambda "&#923;">
```

This gives me

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <!DOCTYPE doc_type [
          <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
          <!ENTITY amp "&#38;">
          <!ENTITY lambda "&#923;">
]>
<body>
     <math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'>
          <mrow>
               <mo>&lambda;</mo>
          <mrow>
     </math>
</body>
```

Now, it parses just fine, thank you.

However, the problem is that I can't add an ENTITY declaration for every possible character entity that might be used in MathML (for example, "part", "notin", and "sum").

How do I rewrite this string so that it can be parsed for any possible character entity that might be included?

Comment: Note that the end tag must be `</mrow>`, otherwise it can't be parsed, because it is not well-formed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a DOCTYPE declaration that refers to the [MathML DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/MathML/appendixa.html#parsing.usingdtd):

```
<!DOCTYPE math 
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD MathML 3.0//EN"
           "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml3/mathml3.dtd">
```

or a local copy of the same.